# Vuetify RadioGroup full width

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i have a vuejs app which looks like this

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-radio-group v-for="i in list" :key="i">
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex md4>
              <v-radio label="Test 1" value="a"></v-radio>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md4>
              <v-radio label="Test 2" value="b"></v-radio>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md4>
              <v-radio label="Test 3" value="c"></v-radio>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-radio-group>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

(https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEErNz)

The Problem is that i want to have the radios in full with, but the css class `v-input__control` which is generated by vuetify blocks this.
Do you have any ideas how i could fix this?

[Wrong -> v-input__control -> width: auto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQWZ7.png)
[Correct -> v-input__control -> width: 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOCDF.png)

Comment: What do you mean? Just remove the noise? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmmOoE

Comment: what css are you trying to apply?

Comment: It should look like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQQLJe But the `v-radio-group`breaks it

Comment: Use `d-flex` class? Not sure if has any side effects: `<v-radio-group  class="d-flex">`

Answer (score 2):

Rithy awnser is almost right but it has 2 problems. The css code affects every control on app (and is not scoped) and v-input__contol class is not accesible by css or your css processor because is scoped inside de control group component. So:

Add a class to your radio group:

```
<v-radio-group class="radio-group-full-width" v-for="i in list" :key="i">
```

Then add the css styles (If you use SCSS, if not, see @JakesInTheSoup answer)

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
 .radio-group-full-width {
   >>>.v-input__control {
     width: 100%
   }
 }
</style>
```

The ">>>" is important because it allows the css to access the embeded component scope

Answer (score 1):

just apply style to overwrite existing class

```
<style scoped>
     .v-input__control {
        width: 100% !important
      }
      .v-label {
        width: 100% !important
      }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nacho Moco's answer worked for me with a slight modification to the braces:

```
<style scoped>
 .radio-group-full-width >>>.v-input__control {
     width: 100%
 }
</style>
```

Comment: You're right. My example works with SCSS and I have not specified it. I have modified it to use SCSS and leave your answer as the correct CSS version. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Nacho Moco's answer worked for me with a slight modification:

```js
<style scoped> 
.radio-group-full-width >>> .v-input--radio-group__input {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

Vue 3 gives an error for >>> and the suggested revision is in https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css. Expected code is in the form :

```
<style scoped>
.a :deep(.b) {
  /* ... */
}
</style>
```

The revised code is :

```
<style scoped>
.radio-group-full-width :deep(.v-input--radio-group__input) {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with [Traxo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1981247/traxo)'s comment. Here was my layout using Vuetify v1.5.11:

```
<v-radio-group v-model="selectedDate" class="radio-container d-flex">
  <v-radio
    class="radio-item"
    color="primary"
    v-for="item of items"
    :key="item.id"
    :value="item"
    :label="'This is an individual item!'"
  ></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

And my CSS:

```
.radio-container {
  max-height: 60vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  .radio-item {
    border-bottom: 0.1rem #E5E5E5 solid;
    padding: 25px;
  }
}
```